# How to remove a component by clicking on another one in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'am new to React and I've got a problem. I'm trying to make an app, like Trello clon. So I need to remove a component if I click on the cross of another one.
Here's what I'm trying to do, but definitely it doesn't work. Appreciate any help!

```js
export default class MainPage extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            InputCallState: false
          }
        this.inputStateHandler = this.inputStateHandler.bind(this);
        this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    }
    
      inputStateHandler(){
        this.setState({
            InputCallState: true
          });
          
        }

        close(){
            this.setState({
                InputCallState: false
              });
        }

    render(){
            return(   
                <div>
                <Link to = '/'><img  className = 'icon' src = 'https://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/3/635/w176h2521393885387122.png' alt = '' /></Link>   
                <div onClick = {this.inputStateHandler} className = 'container'>
                    <span onClick = {this.close} className = "close"></span>
                    <h1 >Create a board...</h1>
                </div>
                    {this.state.InputCallState ? <AddForm /> : <div></div>}
                </div>
            );
    }



}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your close method, stopPropagation since its nested and effects the toggle:

```
close(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
...
```

Also, if you don't want an empty div to render, you can instead write

```
{this.state.InputCallState && <AddForm /> }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped me:)